# Fire off an activity indicator while waiting for next page to appear

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, segue

So here is my situation.

I am segueing from on page to another and the second view takes a really long time to load.  I'd like to fire off an activity indicator.  I've tried various combinations and I can't get things to work correctly.  My guess is that both the Segue and activity indicator are on the main thread and so there is no time for the activity indicator to update because somehow the thread is blocking.

When the user clicks the link it fires off the Activity button action:

My current implementation is here - I'm sure there is an easy fix.

```
- (IBAction)activityButton:(id)sender {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[self activityIndicator] startAnimating];
    });
    [self performSelector:@selector(segueToPastFlights) withObject:self];

}

-(void)segueToPastFlights {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PastFlightSegue" sender:self];
}
```

If I don't actually do the segue the indicator starts spinning fine...

Answer (score 0):

AhHA!

The fix was to actually do the segue in the background:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(segueToPastFlights) withObject:self];
```

becomes

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(segueToPastFlights) withObject:self];
```

And all works as hoped!

Comment: What takes time to load? You shouldn't be triggering UI changes on a background thread...

Comment: ViewDidLoad in my next segue if processing a bunch of data to display on the screen (apparently)

Comment: Well, the controller should show the activity indicator and the data loading should be done in the background and update the UI when complete...